# select the trailer part of the string pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a string as below where in need to select only the last part of the string using pyspark
Input
/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_
/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_
Output
fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_
fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_

i am using the code below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.sql("""select stack(1,"/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_","/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_") as (txt)""")
df.withColumn("extract",regexp_extract(col("txt"),"_(.*)",1)).display(10,False)
```

and my output is
*store_abcxyz_lmn*
*store_schu_lev_bsd_s*

however my requirement is

fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_
fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_

could you please help in the above challenge

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"Path": "/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_"}, 
                            {"Path": "/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_ "}])

df.show(2, False)

+------------------------------------------------------+
|Path                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_     |
|/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_ |
+------------------------------------------------------+

df.withColumn("result", F.reverse(F.split(F.reverse("Path"), "/")[0])).show(2, False)

+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|Path                                                  |result                    |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_     |fsp_store_abcxyz_lmn_     |
|/dbfs/mnt/abc/date=20210224/fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_ |fsp_store_schu_lev_bsd_s_ |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```